MSP430FR6989 ADC Voltmeter
I am working on a project that converts a ADC signal to display a voltage on my BoosterPack Mk II. My code is working however I would like to display decimal places of the voltage it is reading. Any ideas on how I could display decimal points?
Here is the code that I have written:
#include <msp430.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "GrLib/grlib/grlib.h"          // TI’s Graphics Library (grlib)
#include "LcdDriver/lcd_driver.h"       // Driver codes for LCD
#include <string.h>

unsigned int ADC_value;

int voltage;

volatile unsigned int i,j,year;

char lcd_str[30];
Graphics_Context g_sContext; // defines a drawing context to be used to draw onto the screen

enum {WELCOME_STATE, VOLTMETER_STATE} state = WELCOME_STATE;



void config_ports()
{
    P8SEL1 |= BIT4; // P8.4SEL ---> A7
    P8SEL0 |= BIT4;
    P1DIR |= BIT0;  // Set P1.0 as output (LED1)
    P1OUT &= ~BIT0; // Initially turn off LED1
    P1DIR &= ~BIT1; // Set P1.1 as input (pushbutton)
    P1REN |= BIT1;  // Enable pull-up resistor on P1.1
    P1OUT |= BIT1;  // Set pull-up resistor to pull up
}

void config_ADC()
{
    ADC12CTL0 |= ADC12ON;    // Turn on ADC
    ADC12CTL1 |= ADC12SSEL_3 | ADC12SHP; // Use SMCLK, enable sampling timer
    ADC12MCTL0 |= ADC12INCH_7; // Select A7 for ADC
}

void toggle_state()
{
    if (state == WELCOME_STATE)
        state = VOLTMETER_STATE;
    else
        state = WELCOME_STATE;
}

void display_welcome()
{
    P1OUT |= BIT0; // Turn on LED1
    // Display welcome message or perform actions for welcome state
        Graphics_clearDisplay(&g_sContext);
        Graphics_drawStringCentered(&g_sContext, "Welcome to", AUTO_STRING_LENGTH, 64, 20, OPAQUE_TEXT);
        Graphics_drawStringCentered(&g_sContext,  "My Voltmeter", AUTO_STRING_LENGTH, 64, 30, OPAQUE_TEXT);
        Graphics_flushBuffer(&g_sContext);
}

void measure_voltage()
{
    P1OUT &= ~BIT0; // Turn off LED1
    ADC12CTL0 |= (ADC12ENC | ADC12SC); // Enable and start conversion
    while (ADC12CTL1 & ADC12BUSY);     // Wait for conversion to complete
    ADC_value = ADC12MEM0;
    voltage = (3.3 * ADC_value)/ 4096.0; // Calculate voltage
    // Display voltemeter message or perform actions for voltemeter state
        Graphics_clearDisplay(&g_sContext);
        Graphics_drawStringCentered(&g_sContext, "Voltmeter", AUTO_STRING_LENGTH, 64, 20, OPAQUE_TEXT);
        Graphics_flushBuffer(&g_sContext);

        // Display voltage value
           sprintf(lcd_str, "Voltage: %d V", voltage);
           Graphics_drawStringCentered(&g_sContext, lcd_str, AUTO_STRING_LENGTH, 64, 30, OPAQUE_TEXT);

           Graphics_flushBuffer(&g_sContext);
}

int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // Stop watchdog timer
    PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;       // Disable GPIO



        // LCD Config: specify SMCLK to 8 MHz in SPI clock
        CSCTL0 = CSKEY;                 // Unlock CS registers
        CSCTL3 &= ~(BIT4|BIT5|BIT6);    // DIVS=0
        CSCTL0_H = 0;                   // Relock the CS registers

        // Graphic Library Config
        Crystalfontz128x128_Init();         // Initializes the display driver
        Crystalfontz128x128_SetOrientation(0);  // Set the LCD orientation
        Graphics_initContext(&g_sContext, &g_sCrystalfontz128x128); // Initialize a drawing context
        Graphics_setBackgroundColor(&g_sContext, GRAPHICS_COLOR_BLACK); // Set the background color to black
        Graphics_setForegroundColor(&g_sContext, GRAPHICS_COLOR_WHITE); // Set the foreground color to white
        GrContextFontSet(&g_sContext, &g_sFontFixed6x8); //Sets the font to be used
        Graphics_clearDisplay(&g_sContext); // force a clear screen


    config_ports();
    config_ADC();

    while(1)
    {
        if (!(P1IN & BIT1)) // Check if pushbutton is pressed
        {


            if (!(P1IN & BIT1)) // Confirm button is still pressed
            {
                toggle_state(); // Toggle FSM state
                while (!(P1IN & BIT1)); // Wait for button release
            }
        }

        switch (state)
        {
            case WELCOME_STATE:
                display_welcome(); // Display welcome message or perform actions
                break;
            case VOLTMETER_STATE:
                measure_voltage(); // Measure voltage and perform actions
                break;
        }


    }

    return 0;
}


In a microcontroller where only integer math is available (or you need the speed or small footprint of it), the typical strategy is to acquire your analog signal at full resolution (or even higher by accumulating-and-dumping / averaging).
This becomes your base resolution, and you may end up with a range (in your case) of 0 to 4096 counts.
For a 3.3 Volt ADC input range (see your datasheet) with a 12-bit analog-to-digital converter, you can have a best/ideal resolution of (3.3 Volts) / (4096 counts), or 0.0008 Volts.
So, if you would like to display 0.001 V, then multiply 3.3 by 1000 to turn it into mV (3300 mV).
Now all of your math can be integer math.
Your original line of:
voltage = (3.3 * ADC_value)/ 4096.0; // Calculate voltage

can become:
analog_input_mV = (3300 * (ADC_value)) >> 12; // Calculate milliVolts as an integer

*( >>12 is a bit level right-shift, the only economical way to do division on a low-power microcontroller).
This (>>12) is the same as  (x/4096).
See: https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp-low-power-microcontrollers-group/msp430/f/msp-low-power-microcontroller-forum/277947/comparison-of-division-and-right-shifting
When you display your number, remember to format and insert the decimal point where it should be to show 0.000 to 3.300 volts.
Of course you're still not making use of your full resolution.  You could multiply by 33000 (notice the extra zero) and move the decimal accordingly when you display the number.
Good luck!

Also, because there are no floating-point operations going on, you need to be sure that you multiply first, then divide.  The variable that you hold the multiplication result in must be large enough to hold the result.  So, for 3300 * 4096 = 13,516,800, or a "long" / int32.  When done in a statement like shown, this is often handled by the compiler when the code is compiled.  However, if for some reason you want to make use of, or manipulate the multiplication result, then the variable where the result is held needs to be of sufficient bit width (like a "long" a.k.a. int32).


Thanks for the help!

@bsouth26 If it was useful, please accept it as an 'answer'.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

You should declare voltage as a float, not as an int.  You already calculate voltage using floats.
If voltage is a float, you can then display it including decimals using sprintf(lcd_str, "Voltage: %f V", voltage);  (%f instead of %d).
You may need additional parameters after %f to set the field width and number of decimal places to show.

I’ve tried that. The Msp430 does not allow floats. I am trying to figure out another way.

@bsouth26 - What compiler are you using? I have used floats (and doubles) on MSP430 MCUs with Code Composer Studio. These are slow MCUs, floats will be slow.

How would I go about doing this?

Can't the poster just have an integer corresponding to hundredths of a volt instead of volts (call it X for now)?  There are so many ways of easily and accurately avoiding floats, and you really gain very little accuracy or precision.  The procedure to display would be to display X/100, then the decimal, then remainder(X/100) assuming X is hundredths of a volt.

@bsouth26 The code should support floats, but the MCU does not have a dedicated floating point core so your build chain will generate integer based code under the hood that will look like floats to you.
